# Django Google News Sitemap

Tags: python, django, sitemap, google-news

Does anyone know how to implement the Google news sitemap standard on Django?
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/sitemaps/news-sitemap

I am struggling to find any mention of how its implemented with Django.

Example of how it should look.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:news="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9">
  <url>
   <loc>http://www.example.org/business/article55.html</loc>
   <news:news>
   <news:publication>
     <news:name>The Example Times</news:name>
     <news:language>en</news:language>
   </news:publication>
   <news:publication_date>2008-12-23</news:publication_date>
     <news:title>Companies A, B in Merger Talks</news:title>
    </news:news>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

What I currently have looks very simple.

```
<url>
<loc>https://example.net/news/this-news-article/</loc>
<lastmod>2022-04-04</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
```

Comment: Can you share your code that produces your current sitemap?  It is difficult to tell you how to change it if we can't see it.

Comment: Try to use

pip install django-news-sitemaps

Answer (score 2):

As of now the question is quite general, as one doesn't have access to the code OP is using.

So, taking that, the goal is to learn how to do it. For that there are at least two GitHub projects that I could find which implement a similar logic. In other words, they can be used to infer how to do it; there's a combination between urls.py, templates, ... in order to reach the desired goal... which isn't super straightforward to put it into an answer.

Here one can find the links to the projects

- Django project created by [callowayproject](https://github.com/callowayproject/django-news-sitemaps). In it you have an application named [news_sitemaps](https://github.com/callowayproject/django-news-sitemaps/tree/master/news_sitemaps) where you can see most of the logic relevant for the sitemap.
- [image-sitemaps](https://github.com/akarzim/image-sitemaps). In it there's an app named [imagesitemaps](https://github.com/akarzim/image-sitemaps/tree/master/imagesitemaps) with the logic i was talking about.

If one is looking for tutorials, these that [DavidW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73023042/django-google-news-sitemap#comment130000479_73593903) shared might be useful:

- [Django Sitemap Tutorial](https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-sitemap-tutorial)
- [How to Create a Dynamic Django Sitemap](https://ordinarycoders.com/blog/article/django-sitemap)